# Electric potential by infinite plates

Tags: electrostatics, potential

I am studying on my own with the book by Professor Moyses Nussenzveig "Course in Basic Physics", and I decided to solve some examples from the book.

In this example, there are two infinite plates, one in the $ xz $ plane with $ \sigma> 0 $ and the other in the $ xy $ plane with $ \sigma <0 $, and I want to calculate the electrical potential between two points, $ a = (1,1,1) $ and $ b = (2,2,2)$. I know that I can find the electric potential from the electric field, so I decided to find the field of this system by the principle of superposition: $$\vec E_{xz} = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}(\frac{y}{|y|}) \hat j$$, $$\vec E_{xy} = \frac{-\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}(\frac{z}{|z|})\hat k$$, so: $$E_{total} = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}((\frac{y}{|y|}) \hat j - (\frac{z}{|z|}) \hat k)$$

I know that $\Delta V = - \int_C E . dl$, but I am having difficulties in how to integrate the field that I acquired. Any help or rectification is welcome. This is my first post, if by chance I formulated my question in a wrong way, please let me know so I can adjust.

Comment: Since there is a region containing $a$ and $b$ where $\vec E$ is constant, the integral should be fairly straightforward.